# invalidate() does not call onDraw(), Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm new in Android and need help.
In my code I use onTouchEven() to move ImageView, but invalidate() doesn't call onDraw(). I'm looking for solution all over the Internet and stil can't see my mistake. Please, help.

map - this is my ImageView I want to drag.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView infoSpace;
    ImageView map;
    ImageButton updateButton;
    String currentDateTimeString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.example.eleizo.firstapplication.R.layout.activity_main); 

        map = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map);

        map.setWillNotDraw(false);
        map.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                new CustomImageView(context).onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    private class CustomImageView extends View {

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    //the active pointer is one currently moving object
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

        public CustomImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            final int action = ev.getActionMasked();


            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    Log.d("DEBUG","MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
                    final float x = ev.getX();
                    final float y = ev.getY();
                    mLastTouchX = x;
                    mLastTouchX = y;
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    Log.d("DEBUG","MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE");
                    final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                    final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                    final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);
                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;
                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;
                    this.setX(x+mPosX);
                    this.setY(y+mPosY);

                    invalidate();
                    Log.d("DEBUG",String.format("AFTER invalidate(): %f %f", mPosX,  mPosY));

                    mLastTouchX = x;
                    mLastTouchY = y;

                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    Log.d("DEBUG","MotionEvent.ACTION_UP");
                    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    Log.d("DEBUG","MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL");
                    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                    Log.d("DEBUG","MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP");
                    final int pointerIndex = ev.getActionIndex();
                    final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

                    if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                        // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                        // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                        final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                        mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                        mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
            Log.d("DEBUG","OnDraw()");
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(mPosX,mPosY);
            canvas.restore();

        }
    }
```

When I touch map I can see log "AFTER invalidate():.."
But never can see log "OnDraw()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new CustomImageView(context).onTouchEvent(event);
```

You're not saving a reference to your CustomImageView object. You're creating an object, calling onTouchEvent yourself, but you're not storing a reference or giving a reference to whichever class calls onDraw.

Maybe make your `map` object of type `CustomImageView` rather than `ImageView`

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand( How can i call setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() if i will not have the map?

Comment: I'm suggesting that instead of having map be of type ImageView, make map be of type CustomImageView. You don't need a separate listener for onTouch that you invalidate, the map itself is what you should call invalidate() on, and you want map's onDraw to be called. you don't need a separate touch listener,

Comment: @Elena is there anything else I can try to clarify? Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: @Elena If my answer solved your original problem, you should mark it as accepted. If you have additional questions, you should post them as separate questions rather than editing in new questions to your original post

Comment: Thanks a lot! Context context = getApplicationContext();
        map = new CustomImageView(context);
        setContentView(map);